# Using yield to run code after method of function execution

Tags: python, oop, pytest, generator, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a class method that can run some code after its execution.

In `pytest` we have this functionality with `fixtures`:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def db_connection(conn_str: str):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_str)
    yield connection
    connection.close() # this code will be executed after the test is done
```

Using this fixture in some test guarantees that connection will be closed soon after the test finishes. This behavior is described [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html), in the Teardown section.

When I try to do it in my own class methods, I didn't get the same result.

```py
class Database:
    def __call__(self, conn_str: str):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_str)
        yield conn
        print("Got here")
        conn.close()

database = Database()
conn = next(database())
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from users")
result = cur.fetchall()
conn.commit()

result
```

The output is the data in users table, but I never see the "Got here" string, so I'm guessing this code after the `yield` keyword never runs.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: All the "magic" is in how `pytest.fixture` makes use of the generator function it decorates and how the `pytest` test runner makes use of fixtures. It has virtually nothing to do with `yield` itself. (This particular fixture is probably implemented similarly to a context manager.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is implement a context manager; the similarly to a Pytext fixture is incidental.

You can do this with `contextmanager.contextlib`

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def db_connection(conn_str):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_str)
    yield connection
    connection.close()

with db_connection(...) as db:
    ...
```

or define `Database.__enter__` and `Database.__exit__` explicitly:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, conn_str: str):
        self.conn_str = conn_str

    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(self.conn_str)
        return self.conn

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("Got here")
        self.conn.close()

with Database(...) as db:
    ...
```

(You can use the connection returned by `psycopg2.connect` as a [context manager itself](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement).)

Comment: I really wanna give you the answer, but it seems @Carcigenicate answer more directly what I've asked. Although, your answer is much more claryfing for me than his. Many thanks!

Comment: @AndréCarvalho Yes, but this is the right answer. What Pytest does is out of necessity due to its design. Trying to replicate its behaviour in a scenario where a context manager would be a standard and much cleaner solution, is... not wise.

Answer (score 1):

You need another `next` call to have it run the code after the yield:

```
database = Database()
gen = database()  # Saved the generator to a variable
conn = next(gen)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from users")
result = cur.fetchall()
conn.commit()
next(gen)  # Triggers the latter part of the function
```

Also note, when you exhaust a generator, it raises a `StopIteration` exception as you'll see. You'll need to catch that as well.

Comment: @AndréCarvalho I'm glad. Note though, there's likely easier ways of doing what you're trying to do unless this was just as a toy test. `__exit__` (context managers) is a far cleaner way of cleaning up resources. It makes far more sense than this odd use of `yield`.